# How to change color buttons of navigation

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

all the words I wrote in the picture
i need  change color buttons of navigation warning color buttons not android:statusBarColor

Comment: Remove `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From API 27 you can use this code:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

in the first line, you set the navigation bar background color and in second-line, you set the navigation bar icon color to light or dark

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your drawable resource file in android in .xml

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```